# Assignment function for Intervals container

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17, complexity

I found the two related questions but they, however, do not answer my question:

- [interval map implementation](//stackoverflow.com/q/50518179)
- [Where exactly does my code not adhere to the specification of the key and value type?](//stackoverflow.com/q/54068482)

The task is as follows:

> Implement 'assign' function for the intervals container `interval_map`:
>
> `interval_map<K,V>` is a data structure that efficiently associates
> intervals of  keys of type `K` with values of type `V`; it is implemented
> on top of `std::map`.
>
> Each key-value-pair `(k,v)` in the `m_map` member means that the value `v`
> is associated  to the interval from `k` (including) to the next key
> (excluding) in `m_map`.
>
> Example: the `std::map` (0,'A'), (3,'B'), (5,'A') represents the mapping
>
> ```
>  0 -> 'A'
>  1 -> 'A'
>  2 -> 'A'
>  3 -> 'B'
>  4 -> 'B'
>  5 -> 'A' 
>  6 -> 'A'
>  7 -> 'A'
> // ... all the way to numeric_limits<key>::max()
> ```
>
> The representation in `m_map` must be canonical, that is, consecutive
> map entries must not have the same value:
>
> ```
> ..., (0,'A'), (3,'A'), ...
> ```
>
> is not allowed.
>
> Initially, the whole range of `K` is associated with a given initial
> value, passed to the constructor.
>
> Key type `K`
>
> - besides being copyable and assignable, is less-than comparable via `operator<` ;
> - does not implement any other operations, in particular no equality comparison or arithmetic operators.
>
> Value type `V`
>
> - besides being copyable and assignable, is equality-comparable via `operator==` ;
> - does not implement any other operations.

Below is my implementation of interval map in C++17 which works correctly but does not pass the efficiency (speed) requirement. The requirement is to use **at most** one operation of O(log N) complexity where N is the number of elements in the map.

Huh.. is it possible at all to achieve this ? Probably using new C++17 map's features like **extract** and **merge** ? But I could not come up with a good solution though..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <set>
#include <limits>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>

#if 1
#define OUTZ(...) std::cerr << __VA_ARGS__ << std::endl;
#else
#define OUTZ(...)
#endif

// Placeholder type exposes only '<' operation on the underlying type T
template < class T >
struct Placeholder {

    typedef T inner_type;
    typedef Placeholder< T > Self;

    Placeholder(T _i) : i(_i) { }

    friend bool operator <(const Self& x, const Self& y) {
        return x.i < y.i;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os,
                  const Self& x) {
        os << x.i;
        return os;
    }
    T i;
};

template<typename K, typename V>
class interval_map {

    friend void IntervalMapTest();
    V m_valBegin;
    std::map<K,V> m_map;

public:
    // constructor associates whole range of K with val
    interval_map(V const& val)
        : m_valBegin(val)
    { }

    // Assign value val to interval [keyBegin, keyEnd).
    // Overwrite previous values in this interval.
    // If !( keyBegin < keyEnd ), this designates an empty interval,
    // and assign must do nothing.
    void assign( K const& keyBegin, K const& keyEnd, V const& val ) {

        if(!(keyBegin < keyEnd)) // empty interval
            return;

        auto [iend,endAdded] = m_map.emplace(keyEnd, val); // NOTE: the value must be adjusted!

        auto eraseEnd = iend;
        if(endAdded) {
            // see if we insert before the first interval
            const auto& vprev = (iend == std::begin(m_map) ? m_valBegin : std::prev(iend)->second);
            if(vprev == val) {
                eraseEnd = std::next(iend); // erase iend if the values are equal
            } else { // need to correct the value of 'keyEnd'
                iend->second = vprev;
            }
        } else { // no insertion has occurred
            if(iend->second == val) {
                eraseEnd = std::next(iend);
            }
        }
        // insert with hint since keyBeg might be located just before keyEnd
        auto ibeg = m_map.insert_or_assign(iend, keyBegin, val);
        auto eraseBeg = std::next(ibeg);
        {
            const auto& vprev = (ibeg == std::begin(m_map) ? m_valBegin : std::prev(ibeg)->second);
            if(vprev == val)
                eraseBeg = ibeg; // erase begin too as we hit
        }

//        OUTZ("Erasing range: [" << eraseBeg->first << "; "
//             << (eraseEnd == end(m_map) ?  Kmax : eraseEnd->first) << ']');

        m_map.erase(eraseBeg, eraseEnd);
    }

    // look-up of the value associated with key
    V const& operator[]( K const& key ) const
    {
        auto it = m_map.upper_bound(key);
        if(it == m_map.begin()) {
            return m_valBegin;
        } else {
            return (--it)->second;
        }
    }

    void print(const std::string& msg = {}) {
        OUTZ("printing: " << msg);
        OUTZ("-oo -- > " << m_valBegin);
        for(const auto& [key, val] : m_map) {
            OUTZ(key << " ---> " << val);
        }
    }

    void clear() {
        m_map.clear();
    }

    //! tests whether intervals satisfy canonical representation
    void intervals_check() {

        const V *pprev = &m_valBegin;
        OUTZ("Checking intervals..");
        for(const auto& [k,v] : m_map) {
           // uncomment this to print intervals in the container
    #if 0
                std::cout << "[" << it->first << "; ";
                if(next != m_map.end())
                    std::cout << next->first << ") = ";
                else
                    std::cout << "+oo) = ";
                std::cout << it->second << "\n";
    #endif
            if(*pprev == v) {
                throw std::runtime_error("FATAL: incorrect intervals..");
            }
            pprev = &v;
        }
    }
};


int main() try
{
    interval_map< Placeholder<int>, char > xmap('?');

    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        int beg = rand() % 20 - 10,
            end = beg + rand() % 100;
        char C = 'A' + rand() % 12;
        xmap.assign(beg, end, C);
        xmap.print();
        xmap.intervals_check();
    }
    return 0;
}
catch(std::exception& ex) {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
catch(...) {
    std::cerr << "Unknown exception!" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I see a couple of reasons why it does not pass the efficiency requirement. First, you erase beg/end immediately after inserting them (in some cases), leading to redundant operations on Key/Value. Second, they state that you should use overloads of `insert/emplace` that take a hint as a parameter. I think their criteria-testing system just straight-up rejects implementations that use `insert/emplace/erase` without a hint. Also, imagine that `emplace_hint` gives up with `assert(false)` if it couldn't insert in amortized constant time.

Answer (score 3):

## Include the correct headers

I don't see a need for these headers:

> ```
> #include <chrono>
> #include <cmath>
> #include <functional>
> #include <iomanip>
> #include <limits>
> #include <memory>
> #include <random>
> #include <set>
> #include <sstream>
> #include <stdint.h>
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <unordered_map>
> #include <vector>
> ```

On the other hand, we need to add these:

```
#include <cstdlib>              // std::srand, std::rand
#include <ctime>                // std::time
#include <iterator>             // std::next, std::prev, std::begin
```

## Avoid macros

This doesn't really require a macro:

> ```
> #if 1
> #define OUTZ(...) std::cerr << __VA_ARGS__ << std::endl;
> #else
> #define OUTZ(...)
> #endif
> ```

One disadvantage is that when compiled out, the arguments don't get parsed, so errors can creep in.

We could just select an appropriate choice of stream (probably not `std::cerr`, given that its usage doesn't seem to be for errors):

```
#if 1
std::ostream& log_stream = std::clog;
#else
std::ofstream log_stream{"/dev/null"};  // Or create a null stream class
#endif
```

Also, we probably don't want to be flushing all of this output, so [prefer plain `'\n'` to heavyweight `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n).

---

## Placeholder class

This seems to be present just to confirm that the interval map doesn't require anything other `<` from the key type, so probably belongs with the test code.

`inner_type` is never used.  Prefer [`using`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) to `typedef` for `Self` (or just omit it).

The constructor is redundant: since `i` is public, the default aggregate initialisation should be fine.

The operators don't need to be `friend`, because `i` is public.

---

The `interval_map` class accepts any type for key and value; we should express the [constraints](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints):

```
#include <concepts>

template<std::copy_constructible K, std::equality_comparable V>
    requires requires(K key) { key < key; }
class interval_map
```

We have declared a friend called `IntervalMapTest` - it would be useful to have some tests, but this seems not to have been implemented.  Definitely consider doing so.

The constructor can reduce copying of large value types using [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move):

```
    interval_map(V val)
        : m_valBegin{std::move(val)}
    { }
```

---

In `assign()`, we are also able to pass `keyBegin` and `keyEnd` by value, and `std::move()` them in arguments to `emplace()` and `insert_or_assign()`.

As you say, the complexity here doesn't meet requirements.  If our map has \$N\$ elements and the added range spans \$R\$ of them, we have:

- `std::map::emplace()`: \$O(\log N)\$
- `std::map::insert_or_assign()`: \$O(\log N)\$
- `std::map::erase()`: \$O(\log N + R)\$

It's not possible to get the desired single \$O(\log N)\$ operation using this representation, due to the `erase()`.  Options available are:

- change the representation (likely harming performance of `operator[]`), or
- use a hand-coded linear search for the start and end positions, leaving `erase()` as the only \$O(\log N)\$ function *called* from `assign()` (which doesn't seem to fit the spirit of the challenge).

---

It's normal for `main()` to return small *positive* values - for example, on my Linux system here, returning -1 results in status 255 received by the invoking shell.  `<cstdlib>` has the macro [`EXIT_FAILURE`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status) for exactly this purpose, and I see no reason not to use it.